# how to access my sqlite databsae via sqlite.exe?

Tags: android, sqlite

I found out during the debug that my db is in:
/data/data/package-name/databases/...
how can i access this db from sqlite.exe (or with another tool) to run query / check what's in my tables to make sure that all fields are correct?

thanks very much! udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sqlite3 util from a shell to an emulator.

Instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

**SQLite Database Browser** is a freeware, public domain, open source visual tool used to create, design and edit database files compatible with SQLite. [You can find it here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Answer (score 1):

As Ran suggested you can use the steps in the mentioned link , you need to use command prompt for it.

If you are using Eclipse IDE try opening DDMS and go to /data/data/package-name/databases/ there you can see your database , select the DB and Pull it on to your computer.

open the DB file with SQLLite3 database browser. You can alter your tables and push it back to the device using the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is in the emulator, you can also do this from your PC command line: 'adb shell', then cd to the database location (/data/data/package_name/databases/) and run 'sqlite3 database.db'. I sometimes use this method for a quick table check, rather than copying the database from the emulator back to my PC.